# Chrome Extension Development - need help getting started

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'd like to try my hand at some Chrome Extension Development. The most I have done with extensions is writing some small Greasemonkey scripts in the past.

I would like to use localStorage to store some data and then reveal the data on a extension button click later on. (Its seems like this would be done with a popup page)

How do I run a script everytime a page from lets say http://www.facebook.com/* is loaded?
How do I get access to the page? I think based off my localStorage requirement I would have to go down the background_page route (correct?) Can the background page and popup page communicate across the localStorage?

**UPDATE:**
I'm actually looking to learn the "Chrome way". I'm not really looking to run an existing Greasemonkey script

Comment: Short answers like Yes/No for the subparts are fine. Thanks.

Comment: Chrome extensions are insanely easy to make. Especially if only `content_scripts` are required. No 'difficult' chrome API's. But even the 'difficult' `chrome.*` API's are insanely simple =) [This is a great page full of example extensions.](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html) (There are a lot, but I suggest you download + try out at least 20. I did and it helped me a lot.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google actually has some pretty good documentation on creating extensions.  I recommend thoroughly reading the following two articles if you haven't already done so:

- http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html
- http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html

If you want to give your extension access when the user browses to Facebook, you'll need to declare that in the extension's manifest.

Unless you're wanting to save data beyond the life of the browser process, you probably don't need to use local storage.  In-memory data can just be stored as part of the background page.

Content scripts (which run when you load a page) and background pages (which exist for the duration of the browser process) can communicate via message passing, which is described here:

- http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Overall, I'd suggest spending some time browsing the Developer's Guide and becoming familiar with the concepts and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a feature to automatically convert greasemonkey scripts to extensions!

Comment: but is there someway to look at the output of a converted script?